# MySQL use one Insert statement instead of cursor loop

Tags: mysql, performance, cursor, insert-into

I have this trigger and it is working well but I read that using cursors and loops is not good for performance..

So How can I replace using cursor and loop by one insert into statement like the that one in update part:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_invoice` AFTER INSERT ON `invoicetbl`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE my_hour INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE my_day INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE my_month INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE current_item_id BINARY(16);
  DECLARE current_item_total_price DECIMAL(11, 2);
  DECLARE current_item_count DECIMAL(11, 3);

  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR     SELECT  item_id, item_total_price, item_count
        FROM  invoice_itemtbl
        WHERE  invoice_id = NEW.invoice_id;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

  SET my_month = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NEW.invoice_date);
  SET my_day = CONCAT(my_month, LPAD(DAY(NEW.invoice_date), 2, '0'));
  SET my_hour = CONCAT(my_day, LPAD(HOUR(NEW.invoice_date), 2, '0'));

  IF NEW.invoice_type = 0 THEN

        OPEN cur;

        start_loop: LOOP

        FETCH cur INTO current_item_id,
                       current_item_total_price,
                       current_item_count;

        IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE start_loop;
        ELSE
```

(continued...)

```
        INSERT
          INTO  sales_result_company_item_month(company_id, currency_id,
                time_value, item_id, result, invoices_count, item_qty )
          VALUES  (NEW.company_id, NEW.currency_id, my_month, current_item_id,
                    current_item_total_price, 1, current_item_count )
          ON DUPLICATE KEY 
          UPDATE  result = result + current_item_total_price,
                  invoices_count = invoices_count + 1,
                  item_qty = item_qty + current_item_count;

        END IF;
        END LOOP;

      CLOSE cur;

  END IF;

  IF NEW.invoice_type = 1 THEN

    //like here:
    UPDATE  sales_result_company_item_month m
    INNER JOIN  
    (
        SELECT  item_id, returns_count, returns_total
            FROM  invoice_returns
            WHERE  return_invoice_id = NEW.invoice_id
    ) f  ON m.item_id = f.item_id SET m.result = m.result - f.returns_total,
        m.item_qty = m.item_qty - f.returns_count
    WHERE  m.company_id = NEW.company_id
      AND  m.currency_id = NEW.currency_id
      AND  m.time_value = my_month;

  END IF;

END
```

(Copied from Comment -- after 'fixing' problem, including the elimination of Cursor):

```
INSERT
     INTO  sales_result_company_item_month
         (company_id, currency_id, time_value, item_id,
          result, invoices_count, item_qty) 
SELECT  NEW.company_id, NEW.currency_id, my_month, t.item_id,
        t.item_total_price, 1, t.item_count
    FROM  invoice_itemtbl t
    WHERE  invoice_id = NEW.invoice_id
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        result = result + t.item_total_price,
        invoices_count = invoices_count + 1,
        item_qty = item_qty + t.item_count;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can probably get rid of the Cursor.

It is possible to do

```
INSERT INTO t ( ... )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
    SELECT ...;
```

In that, the `SELECT` fetches all the rows to "upsert".  You will probably need `VALUES()` in the `UPDATE` clause to distinguish between selected columns and the columns already in the table.  See examples in the manual.

If you wish to discuss this question further, please

- Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables,
- Get rid of the kruft (eg, my_day, which is not used)
- Prefix local variables with `_`, or otherwise distinguish them from table columns.

`current_item_count DECIMAL(11, 3)` puzzles me:  What "count" needs 3 decimal places?

Comment: thank you very much. this is the result query: `INSERT INTO sales_result_company_item_month (company_id, currency_id, time_value, item_id, result, invoices_count, item_qty)
  SELECT NEW.company_id, NEW.currency_id, my_month, t.item_id, t.item_total_price, 1, t.item_count FROM invoice_itemtbl t WHERE invoice_id = NEW.invoice_id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE result = result + t.item_total_price, invoices_count = invoices_count + 1, item_qty = item_qty + t.item_count;`

Comment: `current_item_count` it was INT(11) and I change the type without changing name. thanks.

Comment: I added your "solution" to your question -- for other readers.